# populate in mongodb with meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am using meteor.js. I am having three collections boards,categories,users.

```
Boards : 
 {
 "_id": ObjectId("su873u498i0900909sd"),
  "locked": NumberInt(0),
 "board_name": "Legends",
  "description": "legends of the world",
   "cat_id":  ObjectId("su873u498i0900909sd"),
  "cost": NumberInt(1),
 "image": "1389249002691_indexhj.jpeg",
"creator": ObjectId("52ce317994acdcee0fadc90c")
}

categories:
{
"_id": ObjectId("su873u498i0900909sd"),
 "user_id": ObjectId("su873u498i0900909sd"),
catname:"hjjj"
 }

users:
{
 "_id":ObjectId(55acec2687fe55f12ded5b4a),
"username" :"mariya"
}
```

from this i want to get username in the users collection which is referred in categories collection with user_id field where the  categories collection is referred in boards collection with cat_id. This is how an trying to get it.

```
 Boards.find({_id:"ObjectId(55acec2687fe55f12ded5b4a)"},function(res){
  if(res){

 categories.find({_id:res.cat_id},function(res1){
   if(res1){
     users.find({_id:res.user_id},function(res3){
      res.send(res3)
     })

   })
 })
```

As using mongoose in meteor will affect the performance i cannot use populate method. So is there any other way to achieve the result rather than above one?

Comment: joins are not really yet officially supported but there are some packages around to help us use that here is one for example: https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite

Comment: Thanks Mark Uretsky.  Let me try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably [collection helpers](https://atmospherejs.com/dburles/collection-helpers).

Basic usage:

```
Boards.helpers({
  creator: function () {
    return Meteor.users.findOne(this.creatorId);
  },
  category: function () {
    return Categories.findOne(this.categoryId);
  }
});
```

Usage in template is pretty simple. Let's say you have your board:

```
{{#each boards}}
  <div>
    <h3>{{board_name}}</h3>
    <p>Created by</p>: {{ creator.username }}
    <p>Category</p>: {{ category.catname }}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Added tip: use [publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) to publish the relationships in a more manageable fashion.

```
Meteor.publishComposite('board', function (boardId) {
  check(boardId, String);
  return {
    find: function () {
      return Boards.find(boardId);
    },
    children: [{
      find: function (board) {
        return Meteor.users.find(board.creatorId);
      }
    }, {
      find: function (board) {
        return Categories.find(board.categoryId);
      }
    }]
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But i have to call this from an other application which i have connected using ddp service. How to connect them?

Comment: I solved it. But facing an another problem. Asked a question regarding the same. Please help me to solve? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717394/publish-composite-with-more-than-one-nested-sub-documents-in-meteor