# publish composite with more than one nested sub documents in meteor

Tags: meteor

I am using meteor.js. I am having three collections boards,lineup

```
Boards : 
 {
 "_id": ObjectId("su873u498i0900909sd"),
  "locked": NumberInt(0),
 "board_name": "Legends",
  "description": "legends of the world",
   "apartments":  [{id:ObjectId("su873u498i0900909sd"),"val":'sdfs','lineup':[ObjectId("su873u498i0900f09sd"),ObjectId("su873u498i0900f09sd")]},{id:ObjectId("s78898973u498i0900909sd"),"val":'sdfs','lineup':[ObjectId("su873u498i0900f09sd"),ObjectId("su873u498i0900f09sd")]}],
  "cost": NumberInt(1),
 "image": "1389249002691_indexhj.jpeg",
"creator": ObjectId("52ce317994acdcee0fadc90c")
}


 lineup:
 {
  "_id": ObjectId("su873u498i0900f09sd"),
 "uid": ObjectId("su873u498i0900909sd"),
  sname:"hjjj"
 }
```

How can i use publish composite to iterate over apartments field in boards and then find data from lineup collections using lineup in apartments

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is a join on the data, and you can do it on the server in `Meteor.publish` by querying for the `lineup` based on the `_id` of the `apartments`, and then using a `transform` function as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895154/how-to-transform-data-returned-via-a-meteor-publish/20896561#20896561).