# Populate subdocument in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, simple-schema, meteor-collection2

I have a schema which has a subdocument defined by another schema like so:

#### Child schema

```
export const Child = new Mongo.Collection('Child');
Child.schema = new SimpleSchema({ ... });
Child.attachSchema(Child.schema);
```

#### Parent schema

```
export const Parent = new Mongo.Collection('Parent');
Parent.schema = new SimpleSchema({
    child: { type: Child },
    ...
});
Parent.attachSchema(Parent.schema);
```

Now, when I read a `Parent` type object, I get a child object's id in its `child` property.

Is there a way I can *populate* the `child` property of parent, so that I can get the whole `Child` object as a subdocument, instead of just a string of id (much like [populating](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) subdocuments in mongoose)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694648/populate-in-mongodb-with-meteor) helpful, although a little longer than simply calling `populate()`