# MongoDB relations child to parent

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, collections

I create an Meteor application where have two collections, ActivityCards and Users. I have a reference to the User inside my ActivityCard collections like this:

```
 {
    "_id" : "T9QwsHep3dMSRWNTK",
    "cardName" : "Guntnauna",
    "activitycardType" : 10,
    "startDate" : "1952-08-09",
    "remainingHours" : 0,
    "activities" : [ 
      {
        "activityName" : "Cfuw",
        "activityTotal" : "5",
        "activityEmployee" : "Smamnktl",
        "activityDate" : "1960-07-16"
      }, 

      ... 
    ],
    "customerID" : "z9hXczmWaf7wgdAtj",
    "isArchived" : 0
}
```

customerID contains an id to the following user collection:

```
{
    "_id" : "9mXAZkmfpKMPvQY8Y",
    "createdAt" : ISODate(),
    "services" : {
      "password" : {
        "bcrypt" : ""
      }
    },
    "emails" : [ 
      {
        "address" : "topony@mailinator.com",
        "verified" : false
      }
    ],
    "profile" : {
      "relationNumber" : "962",
      "companyName" : "Snider Kinney Co",
      "locationStreet" : "Ullamco eaque consequatur aspernatur consectetur eiusmod eligendi enim rerum consectetur asperiores officia eius itaque expedita dolorum",
      "locationPostal" : "Sit inventore asperiores est anim commodo non fugiat consequat Voluptatem tempore sunt culpa magni",
      "locationCity" : "Ipsum et fugit pariatur Nobis eveniet neque veniam perferendis eius ut quo excepteur consequatur voluptatem architecto",
      "contactName" : "Julian Moran",
      "contactPhone" : "+388-14-8339022",
      "isArchived" : 0
    },
    "roles" : {
      "customers" : [ 
        "customer"
      ]
    }
}
```

I am new to MongoDB and don't know if this is a properly configured relation In the documentation I mostly find relations from parent to child and not the other way around.

I am wondering what would you guys suggest for this type of relation. 
How to save them, get the data from both collections, etc.

If my code can be used I would like to know how to get the relations from child to parent and display them. currently I only used the find() method from MongoDB and mapped the data into separate values.

Answer (score 0):

You can have such a relation in your mongodb collection. If you are using mongoose you can define them in your schema like this:

```
customerId:{{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'user' }}
```

and you can reach the parent from child with `mongoose populate`.
for more information see

> https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: I use Meteor without mongoose. Perhaps you know how to access data with Meteor and the default MongoDB package?

Comment: see this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694648/populate-in-mongodb-with-meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694648/populate-in-mongodb-with-meteor)